# check what type of .csv should import into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 type of .csv one ends with "," and one ends with ";"

How can I set the php to chose which csv file to import? ( the .csv name is dynamic )

```
foreach (glob("*.csv") as $filename) {
$csvfile = ($filename);
}
```

my php code:

```
$affectedRows = $pdo->exec( 
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' 
INTO TABLE $databasetable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@dummy, name, data, value)");

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec( 
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' 
INTO TABLE $databasetable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(name, data)");
```

Comment: Read the first line of the file. Check whether it contains `;` or `,`.

Comment: i need the php script with IF else... IF ";"  enter on first script with (@dummy, name, data, value) ELSE  load second script with (name, data)

Comment: `if (strpos($first_line, ';') !== false) ... else ...`